# Google webmaster showing duplicate meta descriptions for search directory

Tags: google, google-search-console, duplicate-content, meta-description, pagination

What is the best way to get rid of this error in Google Webmasters?  Do I really need to add "- Page 2" at the end of the descripton?

**Page Description**

```
Kansas basketball tournaments posted by organizations and teams for youth, AAU, and NCAA certified e
```

**Pages**

```
/youth-basketball-tournaments/kansas
/youth-basketball-tournaments/kansas?page=2
/youth-basketball-tournaments/kansas?page=3
/youth-basketball-tournaments/kansas?page=9
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually in that situation, where you have one long document spread through multiple pages, you want to link the pages together using the next and previous links in your `<head>` tag.

For example, for page 3 you could have something like this:

```
<link rel="prev" type="text/html" title="Page 2" href="/youth-basketball-tournaments/kansas?page=2"/>
<link rel="next" type="text/html" title="Page 4" href="/youth-basketball-tournaments/kansas?page=4"/>
```

Hopefully you can get your system to do that automatically for you...

As you are at it, you may want to include the "top" and "up" links.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Canonical tag:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: Can you explain why the canonical tag would help this situation and include an example of how it is used here on this website?   This answer is not high quality because it is so short and mostly a link.

Comment: I think that one reason for this answer would be because, before Google supported the Next and Previous, they used the Canonical in this very same situation. It is wrong as of ... quite a few years now, though.